# How to load previous content like GitHub?

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, user-experience

When I'm on GitHub and I browse some folder, the content loads dynamically :

- address bar is updated
- main content is updated

When I click on previous of my web browser to roll back :

- address bar recovered his previous url
- **main content recovered his previous content.**

For my own site, I can load content dynamically (in jQuery).
But when I roll back, only my address bar is updated. The content doesn't change. :(

How can I get my previous content when I click on previous ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the jquery-address plugin.

https://github.com/asual/jquery-address

Comment: Interesting, I'll checkout ! Thanks.